# Calculating the current of an AC circuit

Tags: ac, circuit-analysis, impedance

[image]

My goal is to calculate the current i(t) up in the right corner. Using the formula $$ Z_{total} = \left( U\over I\right), I = \left( U\over Z_{total}\right) $$

Given values are

$$
R_{1} = 1k \Omega,\
R_{2} = 0.5k \Omega,\
R_{3} = 0.4k \Omega,\
C_{1} = 1 \mu  F,\\
C_{2} = 1 \mu  F,\
L_{1} = 2H,\
e(t) = 10sin(1000t),\
\omega = 1000 $$
The internal impedance of the source is $$
Z_{i} = 10e^{j\pi/4}k \Omega
$$

I start with the parallell connection between
$$ Z_{R2}//Z_{C1} =  \left( Z_{R2}*Z_{C1}\over Z_{R2}+Z_{C1}\right) = \ 
\left( 500*\left( 1\over 0.001j\right) \over500+\left( 1\over 0.001j\right)\right) = -400 + 200j
$$

Ztotal:
$$ Z_{total} = Z_{R1} +Z_{R2}//Z_{C1}+Z_{C2} + Z_{R3} +Z_{L1} + Z_{i} $$
Im not sure if the **internal impedace** of the source Z(i) is supposed to be added to the total impedance as if it is connected in series with the rest of the impedances? If it is I get the following.

$$ Z_{total} = 1000 +(-400 + 200j) -1000j + 400 + 2000j + 10\times1000(\cos(\pi/4)+j\sin(\pi/4)$$
$$= (1000+5000\sqrt2)+j(1200+5000\sqrt2) $$

Now I use the formula above, since the current goes from + to - I get a negative voltage.
$$
I = \left( -U\over Z_{total}\right) = \left( -10\over (1000+5000\sqrt2)+j(1200+5000\sqrt2)\right) $$
$$=0.000865e^{-j0.007976} $$
$$= 0.000865\sin(1000t-0.007976) $$
Does this make any sense?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What ever you have done is correct except at the last step.

The current flows from +ve terminal to -ve terminal and the current \$i(t)\$ marked in the schematic is in the same direction. So the voltage you have to consider is +U. That will change the phase angle by \$\pi\$. ie.,
$$I = \left( U\over Z_{total}\right) = \left( 10\over (1000+5000\sqrt2)+j(1200+5000\sqrt2)\right)$$
$$ = 0.000865e^{-j(0.007976+\pi)}$$ 
$$= 0.000865\sin(1000t-0.007976-\pi)$$

The ac current through the circuit is going to be a sinusoid with same frequency as the voltage source, phase shifted (lag) by \$\mathbf{0.007976+\pi}\$ and peak value of \$0.865mA\$.

Since there are reactive elements in the circuit, the current will have a phase difference from the voltage. So this makes perfect sense.